# C# Validation Pattern - Best practice to validate an Entity over a certain operation

Tags: c#, validation, design-patterns, entity

I might be trying to solve this problem in a wrong way and I've also found lots of solutions but none of them answer my particular question.

In short, I want to validate an object (i.e. argument, entity, etc.) over a an operation (i.e. Insert, Update, Select, etc.).

I've created a small code sample here only for 1 class and 2 operations. But in my actual project, there are many more classes like Person and operations.

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public DateTime Birthdate {get;set;}
   public BeverageSelectionType BeverageSelection {get;set;}
}
```

BeverageSelectionType.cs

```
public enum BeverageSelectionType
{ 
    NotSet,
    Juice,
    Beer,
    Water
}
```

IService.cs

```
public interface IService
{
   void Update(Person person);
   Person Add(Person person);
}
```

PersonSevice.cs (To explain it simple, I chose as `service`, but in reality I use `repository pattern` and `UnitOfWork` which I thought writing them here would be long)

```
public class PersonService : IService
{
    public void Update(Person person)
    {
        if(person.BeverageSelection == BeverageSelectionType.NotSet
           || (person.BeverageSelection == BeverageSelectionType.Beer && person.Birthdate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
          )
         throw new MyInvalidException("Parameters NOT valid for UPDATE operation");

         //Do update with expected parameters
    }

    public Person Add(Person person)
    {
        if(person.Birthdate <= DateTime.MinValue || person.Birthdate >= DateTime.MaxValue)
         throw new MyInvalidException("Parameters NOT valid for ADD operation");

         //Do add with expected parameters
    } 
}
```

I need to design such **as generic as possible** approach for Validation that helps to validate entities ***against operations***. I just don't want to add validation logic in to each service.

Here is another approach that **every** Entity knows itself **when** and **how** it is valid but I though was useful but still believe not good enough:

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public DateTime Birthdate {get;set;}
       public BeverageSelectionType BeverageSelection {get;set;}

   public bool IsValid(ModelValidationType modelValidationType)
   {
       switch(modelValidationType)
       {
           case ModelValidationType.Update:
               if(person.BeverageSelection == BeverageSelectionType.NotSet
           || (person.BeverageSelection == BeverageSelectionType.Beer && person.Birthdate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
          )
          return false;

           case ModelValidationType.Add:
            if(person.Birthdate <= DateTime.MinValue || person.Birthdate >= DateTime.MaxValue)
             return false;
       }

     return true;
   }
}
```

How would you implement the most proper validation approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

following the way I would implement it. After the code some clarification.

```
public class Person
{
    private int id;
    private DateTime birthdate;
    private BeverageSelectionType beverageSelectionType;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        if(birthdate <= DateTime.MinValue || birthdate >= DateTime.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(birthdate));

        id = 0
        Name = name;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public void OrderBeverage(BeverageSelectionType beverageSelectionType)
    {
        if(beverageSelectionType == BeverageSelectionType.Beer $$
           birthdate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Person is not old enough for beer, sorry bro")
        }

        this.beverageSelectionType = beverageSelectionType;
    }
}
```

**1. Private fields over properties**

I would always recommend to hide everything thats not important to the outside. This is basic encapsulation or information hiding. If you dont have a strong reason to make something public, dont do it.

**2. Constructor**

Your person seems to need always a name and a birthdate. Because of that, I would ensure this with a constructor. Do you have a reason to instantiate a invalid object? If no -> dont let it happen.

**3. Method with 'eager validation'**

In this example, validation happens in your method. This is good because your client code can operate on that and decide what to do before persistence is triggered.

In general you mix two things in one class. One is the concept of a person and one the concept of an order. I would recomend to not break this abstractions. I would suggest that your person class offers something like

```
public bool IsAdult();
```

And some Order class that gets a person and your beverage selection and determines if it is a valid order or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'll check it in detail very soon.